# Upgrade from Weblogic 10.3.6 to 12.1.3

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I installed Weblogic 12.1.3 and have had nothing but problems.

I didn't upgrade an existing domain. I created a new one and tried deploying the application to it. It immediately started bombing out on JSP compilation.

```
Compilation of JSP File '/WEB-INF/pages/common/layout/MainLayout.jsp' failed:
MainLayout.jsp:112:41: This attribute is not recognized.
                    <custom:UserMessage type="INFO"    message="${TopInfoMsg}"    messageContainerId="TopInfoContainDiv"    messageDivId="TopInfoMsgDiv"    hide="${empty TopInfoMsg}"    />
```

I've tried the following to troubleshoot:

- Java 7 and Java 8 (problem occurs in both versions)
- Tried the JSP Backwards Compatibility setting in the WLS console
- Disabled JRebel
- Tried eliminating "xerces hell" as a problem by adding xml-apis to the `<prefer-application-packages>` in weblogic.xml (also eliminated the tertiary dependency on that package in my Maven POM file).
- Put the @page tag with pageEnconding="UTF-8" as the first line of the MainLayout.jsp file.

What I occasionally see is weblogic emptying the contents of the .tag files, but not always.

Any help or troubleshooting ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the complete error message and the jsp code involved in this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You should write the content of MainLayout.jsp:112:41 with lines 111 and 113, with its we can try to help you.